# Comparing Exception Objects in Python

Tags: python, exception, comparison

I am new at Python and I'm stuck at this problem. I am trying to compare two "exception objects", example:

```
try:
    0/0
except Exception as e:
    print e
>> integer division or modulo by zero

try:
    0/0
except Exception as e2:
    print e2
>> integer division or modulo by zero

e == e2
>> False

e is e2
>> False
```

How should I perform this comparison to obtain a "True"?

What I am trying to do:

```
class foo():
    def bar(self, oldError = None):
        try:
            return urllib2.urlopen(someString).read()                   
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 400: 
               if e != oldError: print 'Error one'
            else: 
               if e != oldError: print "Error two"
            raise
         except urllib2.URLError as e:
             if e != oldError: print 'Error three'
             raise

class someclass():        
    # at some point this is called as a thread
    def ThreadLoop(self, stopThreadEvent):
        oldError = None
        while not stopThreadEvent.isSet():
            try:
                a = foo().bar(oldError = oldError)
            except Exception as e:
                oldError = e
            stopThreadEvent.wait(3.0)
```

(probably some syntax error)

Why I am doing that?
Because I don't want to print the same error twice

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? I have given an answer, but I imagine there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: I updated the question, your answer was perfect to my (generic) original question, but unfortunately it will not work on my problem (if I have two exceptions of the same type, but different attributes, I need a "true" for equality comparison)

Comment: Your description is how mine works.

Comment: Sorry I'm rephrasing: e1 == e2 -> e1.attributes == e2.attributes AND e1.type == e2.type, e1 != e2 -> e1.attributes != e2.attributes OR e1.type != e2.type [not python, just generic code]

Comment: That's the opposite of what you stated. In which case, you want @nneonneo's answer.

Answer (score 30):

With most exception classes, you can test for functional equality with

```
type(e) is type(e2) and e.args == e2.args
```

This tests that their classes are exactly identical, and that they contain the same exception arguments. This may not work for exception classes that don't use `args`, but to my knowledge, all standard exceptions do.

Comment: I think this is slightly better than Lattyware's answer for the simple reason that this one actually tells you if the exceptions have equivalent arguments, which is not the same as whether they're both instances of the same class. You might have two exceptions of the same class that were raised with different arguments; this gives you more "equivalency" in that regard. My only comment is the same as @Lattyware's below: `type()` is better than `__class__`.

Comment: As a note, I really dislike the use of `e.__class__` here - `type()` exists for a reason, and if you want the type of an object, it's the way to access it.

Comment: @Lattyware: OK, I will use `type`. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho It entirely depends on what the OP wants - I can't think of a situation where you would want to do this, so I don't know if the OP wants equivalency to that level. The OP really needs to explain more about what he wants before anyone could say which answer is preferable.

Comment: @Lattyware a fair point, and after some consideration, I can't think of such a situation either. Given the elaboration in his answer, your answer should do the trick.

Comment: @Lattyware: What about wanting to test whether two `KeyError`s refer to the same missing key? Or whether two `IOError`s are actually the same `errno`? (Yes, there are class-specific ways to do the check, but using `.args` gives you a nice generic way to do it).

Comment: @nneonneo My 'not seeing a point to this' was to the whole idea of checking if two exceptions are the same. I don't see a case where it's going to be needed (or the best way to handle the issue).

Comment: @Lattyware: Fair point. I don't see much point in it either, but occasionally weird solutions are required for weird problems.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to SO and English is not my mother tongue, but I think this one will work for me (need to check if all exceptions I am handling use args), but both are a accurate to my (generic) initial question.

Comment: @Pedro, if they're exceptions derived from the standard Exception class, and especially if they're in common (or Standard) libraries, they *should*. It might be better to rethink your code structure so that you don't need this check, though – whether by letting the exception propagate further, or simply by restructuring to only be in a place to flag the Exception once. Moreover, if you're really generating an exception more than once, why *wouldn't* you want to at least log it each time?

Comment: Because it is a high frequency periodic thread dealing with HTTP requests. For example: if the server is off, it will give me an `urllib2.URLError` per  3 seconds. The "exception compare" would be a simple solution, but, as it do not work exactly as I was expecting, I will rethink the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You want [to check](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#isinstance) [the type of the exception](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> isinstance(e2, type(e))
True
```

Note, naturally, this will allow for subclasses - this is a weird thing to do, so I'm not sure what behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: FWIW, autopep8 converts `type(e) is type(e2)` to `isinstance(e, type(e2))`. It's still probably worth adding another assert with `e.args == e2.args` though.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, comparing the exception message using str() would be useful.

```py
...
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 400: 
                if isinstance(oldError, type(e)) and str(e) != str(oldError): 
                    print 'Error one'
            else: 
                if isinstance(oldError, type(e)) and str(e) != str(oldError): 
                    print "Error two"
            raise
         except urllib2.URLError as e:
             if isinstance(oldError, type(e)) and str(e) != str(oldError): 
                 print 'Error three'
             raise
...
```