# How can i test for ValueError returned in body

Tags: python, pytest

I have the test:

```
# Should return 400 if no name is provided
    def test_no_name(self):
        sut = SignUpController()
        http_request = {
            "email": "any_email",
            "password": "any_password",
            "password_confirmation": "any_password"
        }
        response = sut.handle(http_request)
        assert response['statusCode'] == 400
        assert response['body'] == ValueError('Missing param: name')
```

And I have the production code:

```
class SignUpController:
    def handle(self, http_request: any) -> any:
        return {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "body": ValueError('Missing param: name')
        }
```

It shows me that the values are not equal

```
E       AssertionError: assert ValueError('Missing param: name') == ValueError('Missing param: name')
E        +  where ValueError('Missing param: name') = ValueError('Missing param: name')
```

I would guess that "assert" thing is wrong..
In Javascript's Jest I do this with toEqual, since I'm comparing 2 objects (Error)
How do I do that in pytest?

Comment: Why are you returning a exception instead of raising it and using `try/except`?

Comment: Because that controller will return a response, and that error message should be in the body of that response

Comment: Exception objects can't be serialized. You should send `str(ValueError(...))`

Comment: Comparing exception objects doesn't work by comparing the messages. Try `print(ValueError('foo') == ValueError('foo'))` and you'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing exemption objects with the equality operator will return False. There are a few ways to do it, for example:

```
e = response['body']
e2 = ValueError('Missing param: name')
assert(type(e) is type(e2) and e.args == e2.args)
```

It is a strange thing to do though.

See here for more info:
[Comparing Exception Objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844131/comparing-exception-objects-in-python)

Comment: Yes, I understand that you can't compare two objects
I just change the test code to:
assert response['body']['error'] == 'Missing param: name'
and the production code to: 
return {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "body": {
                "error": "Missing param: name"
            }
        }
Thanks

Comment: I am glad you solved the issue. If my answer worked for you, could you please accept it?