# Why Exceptions cannot be tested for equality / behavior of Exception.__eq__

Tags: python

Why do Exception objects not allow for equality comparison?

Even if they are constructed with same arguments they are not considered equal:

```
 Exception("X") == Exception("X")
 -> False
```

What is the rationale behind this?

Python version is 3.9.7

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be otherwise. If you raise two exceptions with the same arguments, they're still two exceptions.

Comment: Beyond that, "rationale" isn't really what we do here -- if you want to talk rationale you should be on the [python-list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list) mailer. We're here to collect answers to narrow, specific practical problems; and not liking a language's design choice is not a practical problem. See [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design)

Comment: (...and the _practical_ question, as opposed to the rationale one, is covered at [comparing exception objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844131/comparing-exception-objects-in-python))

Comment: The default for comparison is _identity_, and those are two separate objects. There's no semantic equality for errors, so no specific `__eq__` implementation. But you can implement it on your own `Exception` subclasses if you want to.

Comment: They *do* allow for equality comparisons. They simply base equality on identity, which is the default way inherited directly from `object`